# Set cell background of cell after value is appended

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that is appending the value in cell D2 then adding one to that cell, basically stacking a list of numbers. To make it more user friendly, I want to activate the latest cell (which works), but I also want to set the background color to cyan for 2 seconds so the user knows exactly where to go.

I have it close, but instead of seeing the cyan color, I'm just seeing the row activate.

Any thoughts?

```
function copynewentry() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var idstoadd = ss.getSheetByName("Resources");
  var fulllist = ss.getSheetByName("Daily");
  var tag = idstoadd.getRange('D2');

  Logger.log("Option#1 - Start")

  // step 1 - get the last row on the target: Full List
  var last_row = fulllist.getRange(1, 1, fulllist.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String).length;
  Logger.log("Step#1 - the last row on fulllist = "+last_row)

  // step 2 - create a target range (or at least the top left corner of the target)
  var targetrange = fulllist.getRange(last_row+1,1);
  Logger.log("Step#2 - the target range will be "+targetrange.getA1Notation())

  // step 3 - create a source range
  // how many header rows
  var numheaderrows = 0
  // so the range will be...
  // var sourcerange = idstoadd.getRange(1+numheaderrows, 1, idstoadd.getLastRow()-numheaderrows, 1);
  var sourcerange = idstoadd.getRange('D2');
  Logger.log("Stewp#3 - the sourcerange = "+sourcerange.getA1Notation());
  
  // step4 - copy from source to target
  // method = range.copyto
  // so copyto from the source range to the target range
  sourcerange.copyTo(targetrange,{contentsOnly:true});
  Logger.log("Step#4 - copied the source range to the target range and flushed");
  
  
tag.setValue(tag.getValue() + 1);


lastRowOfCol(1); //Enter the column number you want to use as the base of the search


  

  // step 6 - apply all the pending changes.
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Logger.log("Step#6 - Flushed the spreadsheet")
  Logger.log("Option#1 - Completed")
  return false;
}

function lastRowOfCol(column) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var total = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, column, total).getValues();
  for (var i = total - 1; values[i] == "" && i > 0; i--) {}
  var last = sheet.getRange(i + 1, column);
  var range = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  sheet.setActiveRange(range);

  const bgColor = last.getBackground();
  last.setBackground('cyan');
  Utilities.sleep(2000);
  last.setBackground(bgColor);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
last.setBackground('cyan');
Utilities.sleep(2000);
```

#### To:

```
last.setBackground('cyan');
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
Utilities.sleep(2000);
```

### Added:

About the following additional question,

> should I be adding multiple spreadsheetapp.flush's throughout my code? i thought just having one at the end sets the code to do every action and not proceed unless the action above is completed. is that not correct?

I think that it is No.

For example, when you want to show the current situation during the script is running, it is required to use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`. When your script is used as a test when the following modification is used,

```
last.setBackground('cyan');
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
Utilities.sleep(2000);
last.setBackground('red');
Utilities.sleep(2000);
last.setBackground(bgColor);
```

the red color cell cannot be seen. On the other hand, when the following modification is used,

```
last.setBackground('cyan');
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
Utilities.sleep(2000);
last.setBackground('red');
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
Utilities.sleep(2000);
last.setBackground(bgColor);
```

the red color cell can be seen.

Comment: Wow. Unreal, so mad at myself that was all it was. many thanks -- one question, should I be adding multiple spreadsheetapp.flush's throughout my code? i thought just having one at the end sets the code to do every action and not proceed unless the action above is completed. is that not correct?

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, I thought that it is a good question. So, I added the explanation using a sample. Please confirm it.

Comment: Wow great - super helpful. thanks for the constant knowledge. if you're up for the challenge, I have a separate question I am beyond struggling with.  I am trying to set print settings via Apps Script. Meaning, print a specific google sheet tab x times to x printer. I've tried so many different options, curious if there is a way to mess with the URL (like exporting to pdf) that could print. My question is here if you're interested:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75587613/how-to-print-google-sheets-tabs-to-different-printers-using-apps-script-or-other

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for replying. About your other question, when I could find an answer, I would like to post it.

Comment: Just a thought here that I'm trying - I'm thinking maybe I can download the Sheet as an Excel file and then print the Excel, seems like VBA could get the job done which makes me think I can do all in one script. Just brainstorming but going to try now. what a crazy thing!